# Does not show html report in the reports folder in my gauge project

Tags: java, maven, gauge

When I execute my gauge maven project, I cannot see the html report in the reports folder. I have the default settings in env property files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the gauge project root, there is a file called `manifest.json`. This file contains the plugins which will be applied to the project. So if you need the html-report for your test executions, you need to mentioned it in the `manifest.json`. If you didn't install that plugin in your machine, in the runtime the plugin will be installed.

You need to check your `manifest.json` file whether it includes the `html-report` plugin.

An example of `manifest.json` file.

```
{
  "Language": "python",
  "Plugins": [
    "html-report",
    "spectacle",
    "json-report",
    "flash",
    "xml-report",
    "screenshot"
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.